# jQuery's .html(): How to get the result with the value of inputs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using the jQuery's .html() attribute in order to get all the `<li>` elements of my `<ul class="answers_list">`.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<ul id="answers_list" class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
    <li class="row">
        <input id="answer_1" type="text" class="form-control answer_text mx-3 mb-3" placeholder="Type a possible answer" required="" style="width:400px;">
        <input id="check_1" type="checkbox" class="answer_checkbox">
    </li>
    <li class="row">
        <input id="answer_2" type="text" class="form-control answer_text mx-3 mb-3" placeholder="Type a possible answer" required="" style="width:400px;">
        <input id="check_2" type="checkbox" class="answer_checkbox">
    </li>
</ul>
```

And my jQuery code is trying to add one more input field to the list when the user clicks an "Add field" button.

```
$('#btn_add_answer').click(function(){
    var list = $('#answers_list').html();
    var answers_number = 1;
    $('#answers_list').find('.answer_text').each(function () {
        answers_number = answers_number + 1;
    });
    $('#answers_list').html(list+'<li class="row"><input id="answer_'+answers_number+'" type="text" class="form-control answer_text mx-3 mb-3" placeholder="Type a possible answer" required="" style="width:400px;"><input id="check_'+answers_number+'" type="checkbox" class="answer_checkbox"></li>');
});
</ul>
```

The problem:
It is working almost perfect, but if the user types anything in the inputs before adding a field, this new field will be added but it will remove what the user typed it all the other fields. How can I prevent this?

Comment: uhm... that looks like a lot of unnecessary work. Just append another list item, and don't use id's.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I need to use id's for the backend.

Comment: Unless you're sending the data as html directly to the backend, teh backend doesn't need the ID's, it's your frontend code that needs the id's to generate the data you're sending to the backend. but they're generally not necessary. Your list items by definition have a zero-based index that is the position they are in the list. You're just repeating that index in the id +1.

Comment: Alright thanks so much. Anyway I don't see the point on voting this on negative. The question is well formulated and it was a lack of knowledge on jQuery. Isn't Stackoverflow for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a reason for you to re-create the list just to add one more item, you can skip that step and just append it.

```
$('#btn_add_answer').click(function(){
    var answer_number = $('#answers_list .row').length + 1;
    $('#answers_list').append('<li class="row"><input id="answer_'+answer_number+'" type="text" class="form-control answer_text mx-3 mb-3" placeholder="Type a possible answer" required="" style="width:400px;"><input id="check_'+answer_number+'" type="checkbox" class="answer_checkbox"></li>');
});
```

Rebuilding the whole list means you end up with default values for all of the inputs that existed already because the value attribute doesn't contain the current value.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the jQuery [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) method for this... And I agree with Kevin B. about the useless usage of the `id` here...

First clone one row when it's unfilled... And keep it in a variable. Then when you need to add a row, [`.append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/) a copy of it *(cloning again)*.

To get the amount of answers, use the [`.length`](https://api.jquery.com/length/) property.

```js
var answerField = $(".row").first().clone();

$('#btn_add_answer').click(function() {

  $("#answers_list").append(answerField.clone());
  console.log( $("#answers_list .row").length + " answers...");
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="answers_list" class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
  <li class="row">
    <input type="text" class="form-control answer_text mx-3 mb-3" placeholder="Type a possible answer" required="" style="width:400px;">
    <input type="checkbox" class="answer_checkbox">
  </li>
  <li class="row">
    <input type="text" class="form-control answer_text mx-3 mb-3" placeholder="Type a possible answer" required="" style="width:400px;">
    <input type="checkbox" class="answer_checkbox">
  </li>
</ul>
<button id="btn_add_answer">Add an answer</button>
```